# How to update Postman collection from Swagger

Tags: java, swagger, postman, swagger-ui, openapi

I use Swagger in a Java app and have a collection that sets the parameters e.g. uuid, name on the corresponding POST requests. However,on every changes on database, the collections should be updated and I fed up with updating the Postman collections manually. I could not found a proper way except from some export approach e.g. [Convert Swagger documentation to Postman Collection](https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/convert-swagger-documentation-to-postman-collection-d67fc95c7b14).

In this stage, I think I make something wrong and there is a better approach as lots of experienced developers use these tools :

**1.** How should I transfer swagger requests to Postman and set the parameters while GET requests and use them while POST/PUT requests?

**2.** How can I update these requests whenever the request parameters are changed on Swagger?

Answer (score 2):

Postman has an manual option to import open-api. But in your case you need a utility. Thankfully postman team has written a converter.

Postman provides an open source project to convert [OpenAPI 3.0 specs to the Postman Collection (v2)](https://github.com/postmanlabs/openapi-to-postman).

It provides a CLI `openapi2postmanv2`

```
$ openapi2postmanv2 -s spec.yaml -o collection.json -p -O folderStrategy=Tags,includeAuthInfoInExample=false
```

Add it to your build process, so you dont have to manually convert.

Answer (score 2):

Postman offers the ability to have a 2-way API sync with your Git Repo.
Update the Git repo with the new OpenAPI spec.
Postman will see the diffs and allow you to pull in the new changes
Then you can push the changes to your collections
[How to Connect to Your Git Repository](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jJHXLVYOh0&feature=youtu.be) (4min)
[Using an External Git Repository](https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/versioning-an-api/#using-an-external-git-repository) (Docs)

Answer (score 1):

you can convert it by using the :

[image]

read more at :

https://praveendavidmathew.medium.com/the-hidden-gem-postman-api-and-documentation-feature-b065ab579dd

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I could juts try it. It is very useful, thanks a lot. But, I am wondering, if it is possible to generate body of POST, PUT, etc. requests for each endpoints and set the necessary values after GET calls? I tried mock feature, but it generates form-data instead of raw json body. Any idea?

Comment: @Rosa it generates as per the schema defined , if in schema it says form data , then form data will be mentioned